# how to get all the classes defined in an ontology, using owlapi in a none deprecated way

Tags: java, stream, owl, owl-api

How can I find all the defined classes using owlapi in Java? I'm aware of the deprecated `getClassesInSignature` method, but the documentation (JavaDocs) are lacking a bit in regards, what should be used instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The modern way is to use the java `Stream`. You can use it like the following :

```
    Stream<OWLClass> stream = ontology.classesInSignature();
    Set<OWLClass> set = ontology.classesInSignature().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    OWLClass[] array = ontology.classesInSignature().toArray(OWLClass[]::new);
```

Comment: Also OWLAPIStreamUtils.asSet(ontology.classesInSignature())